# Finding the annihilator of polynomials that span a space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the vector space $P_3[x]$ over $\mathbb{R}$.   Let $W$ be the span of $\{f_1, f_2\}$, where $f_1 = x^3 − 2x^2 + x$ and $f_2 = x^2 − x$. Find $W^o$.

Since $W$ is the span of the the above mentioned polynomials I took at the the following polynomial

$c_1f_1+c_2f_2=c_1x^3+(-2c_1+c_2)x^2+(c_1-c_2)x$

If I'm not mistaken, this shows that $c_1,c_2=0$.  Is this saying that the annihilator is just the zero polynomial: $f(x)=0$?

Comment: I'm not certain that you are clear about what $W^0$ means, because being a linear space it cannot be empty. Would you please write down the definition that you consider?

Comment: It's the set of linear functionals of a vector space $V$ such that $f(v)=0$ for all $v$.

Comment: I see what you mean now, I typed out something before I thought about it.

Comment: Still something wrong in your edit: as you said, elements of the annihilator are functionals on $P_3[x]$. They are not polynomials themselves. Secondly, your equality is true, but it shows nothing, it is just an equality, not an equation.

Comment: Hint: look at the map $P\mapsto P(0)$.

Comment: Let me state the definition more formally:  Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ and let $S$ be a subset of $V$.  The annihilator of $S$ is the set $S^0$ of linear functionals $f$ on $V$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$ for every $\alpha \in S$.

Comment: Sure. That's the definition. So you see that the annihilator of $S$ is not made of elements of $S$. (quote: *the annihilator is just the zero polynomial*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.**

Consider the functionals $$P\longmapsto P(0) \qquad 
\text{and} \qquad P\longmapsto P(1)$$
Do they vanish on $W$? Are they linearly independent? What should be the dimension of $W^0$?

Note that in coordinates, $P\mapsto P(0)$ is just $(a_3,a_2,a_1,a_0)\mapsto a_0$ and  $P\mapsto P(1)$ is just $(a_3,a_2,a_1,a_0)\mapsto a_3+a_2+a_1+a_0$.

Comment: It should have dimension $3$.  The rank of the coefficients matrix is $2$, so the dimension of the $W^o$ is $1$.

Comment: Not sure I follow you there. The dimension of $P_3[X]$ is $4$, right?

Comment: But $W$ is a subspace of $P_3[x]$.  The subspace $W$ is spanned by those two polynomials.

Comment: Yes, and it has dimension $2$. Where did you get $1$ and $3$ from?

Comment: I've thought about this more and here is where I'm at.  First, since $W$ is spanned by $f_1$ and $f_2$, does this mean that $P(1)=c_1f(1)+c_2f_2(1)$?  It disappears over $W$.  Where I'm stuck is showing that $W^0$ has dimension $2$ (I'm assuming that this is where you are going?).  There's something about the annihilator of a subset that just isn't clicking with me right now.

Comment: In finite dimension any linear functional is the dot product with some vector,  assuming that you have defined a dot product. By this correspondence $ W^0 $ is isomorphic to the orthogonal of $ W $ wrt your dot product.

Comment: Does this mean that $W^0=\{P(1) ,P(0)\}$?

Comment: This is a set with two elements, what you need is a subspace of dimension two. Plus, $P(0)$ and $P(1)$ don't make sense as functionals, you need to write $P\mapsto P(1)$...

Comment: That's true.  Could I rephrase it as $W^0=\text{span}\{P(0),P(1)\}$

Comment: That's much better! Now again $P(0)$ here is an abuse of notation as they would say.

Comment: I guess I'm just trying to find something more explicit.  Something more than $\text{span}\{P\to P(0),P\to P(1)\}.$  In my "idealized" answer I keep trying to find a linear combination of some stuff to get a more explicit functional.

Comment: Your last suggestion is perfectly written. If you don't like this notation, you always have the "coefficient" version (I updated my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Complete the set $\{f_1, f_2\}$ to a basis of $P_3[x]$: $\{ f_1,f_2,v_1,v_2  \}$

Every linear functional $F$ on the space can be written as:

$F\Big(a_1\cdot f_1+ a_2 \cdot f_2+ a_3 \cdot v_1 + a_4 \cdot v_2 \Big)= a_1 \cdot F(f_1)+ a_2 \cdot F(f_2) + a_3 \cdot F(v_1) +a_4 \cdot F(v_2) $

A functional is in the annihilator if and only if $F(f_1)=0$ and $F(f_2)=0$ (The definition is that $F\vert_W=0$, but this is equivalent).

Comment: I sort of understand what's going on here after I have reread and written out the definition.  $W^o$ is still the set functionals over the bigger space $V$ such that $F(f)=0$ for all $f \in W$.  But $f_1,f_2$ only equal $0$ when $x=0$

Comment: A functional is a linear map from $P_3[x]$ into the field. It does not matter neccessarily what values do elements in $P_3[x]$ take. I'm not sure that every functional on this space is given by assigning  a point. in the element as a function.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what the annihilator is doing explicitly in this case.  I understand that $F$ are the functionals on $V$ such that $F(f)=0$.  I'm having problems explicitly trying to see what's going on.  I'm not sure about what is not clicking about this problem.